# How to print the result of the match from strpos in php

Tags: php

I have here a function for stripos with multiple needle.

```
function strposa($haystack, $needles=array()) {
$chr = array();
    foreach($needles as $needle) {
        $res = stripos($haystack, $needle);
        if ($res !== false) $chr[$needle] = $res;
    }
        if(empty($chr)) return false;
        return min($chr);
}

$needles = array('Apple', 'Orange', 'Mango');
$haystack = "I love apple";

if(strposa($haystack,$needle)) {
    echo "found a match!"; 
    //print apple here
}
else {
    echo "no match found.";
}
```

The function is working fine. What I want is to print the result of the match from haystack. in this case I want to print the word "apple". how should i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give a try to this :

```
function strposa($haystack, $needles=array()) {
$chr = array();
    foreach($needles as $needle) {
        $res = stripos($haystack, $needle);
        if ($res !== false)
        {
            $chr[$needle] = $res;
            $string_exist = $needle; break;
        }
    }
    if(empty($chr)) return false; 
    return $string_exist;
}

$needles = array('Apple', 'Orange', 'Mango');
$haystack = "I love apple";

$match_found = strposa($haystack,$needles);

if($match_found) {
    echo $match_found ;
    //print apple here
}
else {
    echo "no match found.";
}
```

There is another way too to achieve the same result :

```
$needles = array('Apple', 'Orange', 'Mango');
$haystack = "I love apple";

function contains($str, array $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $a) {
        if (stripos($str,strtolower($a)) !== false) return $a;
    }
    return 0;
}

echo contains($haystack, $needles);
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for posting this code. this is a good example. this deserved two up votes :)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
function strposa($haystack, $needles=array()) {
$chr = array();
    foreach($needles as $needle) {
        $res = stripos($haystack, $needle);
        if ($res !== false) $chr= $needle;
    }
        if(empty($chr)) return false;
        return $chr;
}

if(strposa($haystack,$needle)) {
    $ans = strposa($haystack,$needle);
    echo $ans; 
    //print apple here
}
else {
    echo "no match found.";
}
```